# ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, promise, axios

I am writing applications in spring boot and react. I am running a server and want to submit a form from the client side. The form should be saved in the database.

I fill out the form and it is saved in the database, but after filling out the form and clicking the "submit" button the page should switch to the main screen of the application, i.e. the `/dashboard` address, but I still stay with the form and when I enter the devtools I get a **ERROR**: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data').`

That is, it comes out that the application itself works, the data is transferred between the client and the server and stored in the database. So the problem lies on the frontend side, specifically on the react side. The message also points to the specific file where the problem is , namely in the file `projectActions.js`

However, I do not know too much about what the problem is specifically, where I made a mistake, that the page after submitting the form is not "reloaded" and returns to the specified address.

Below I send the class referenced in the error.

I also provide the versions of the packages I use:

```
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
```

**projectActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_ERRORS } from "./types";

export const createProject = (project, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/project", project);
    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: error.response.data,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: `error.response` is not always defined. Check the docs, to see how the object looks like: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem, Indo has a similar issue and could not resolve it yet.  My teammate doesn't get this error in a windows environment and I have a Linux environment. Is there any system-specific reason that could create this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is inside `catch` block, you are trying to read `error.response.data`, and problem is because there is no `response` attribute on error, it is undefined, and when you try to read `data` on undefined you will end up with this error.
Depending on error type `error` will have different structures. Please read this to get idea how to handle axios error(you need safe checks): [axios-error-handling](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I don't really understand now why it reads error.response.data right away or if the application detects the error right away. Could you please tell me how I could handle or rather define the response attribute so that it is minimally handled.

Answer (score 0):

problem is at

```
 payload: error.response.data,
```

if you are sure that most of your error has this structure, you can use  payload: error?.response?.data .

Keep in mind, I really didn't see a error.response.data structure in an error message before. So it is best you change the way you handle the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And maybe you have an idea how I could handle the error message, I don't expect some elaborate logic.

Comment: That really depends on the API. What I mean, if you created the API yourself, so you will know the structure of your own type of error. But if it is not yours, then you should put conditions. Like if error.code == 401, dispatch(something) else {do something else}